# Qml / Qt - 'PathLine' - Controlling Spread of Elements

Tags: qt, qml

I'm unable to figure out how to control the spread of elements when using PathLine in Qml.

At the moment everything is perfect except the overall spread is too large so elements are being cut off. Currently three elements are present on screen which is the intention.

All I want to do is pull them in closer to each other.

This is the code:
(root is the initial Rectangle, root.width is the same size as the application's width so if full screen on a 1080p screen it will be 1920 (as in, 1920x1080), appModel.count is how many elements in the list)

```
path: Path {
    objectName: "path"
    startX: 0
    startY: 0
    PathLine { objectName: "pathLine"; x: appModel.count * root.width / 2; y: 0}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unaware of a command that was bought to my attention elsewhere that invalidates my solution.

`pathItemCount` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathview.html#pathItemCount-prop